# Testing a TCP/IP server locally

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, netcat, tcpserver

I have written an echo TCP server in C.

I wish to test my code to see if it works.

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 500
#define LISTEN_BACKLOG 50

#define handle_error(msg) \
   do { perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } while (0)

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   struct addrinfo hints;
   struct addrinfo *res, *rp;
   struct sockaddr_storage peer_addr;
   socklen_t peer_addr_len;
   int sfd, cfd;

   if(argc != 3) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s address port\n", argv[0]);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
   hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
   hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
   hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
   hints.ai_protocol = 0;
   hints.ai_addr = NULL;
   hints.ai_next = NULL;

   if(getaddrinfo(argv[1], argv[2], &hints, &res) != 0)
      handle_error("getaddrinfo");

   // Try each socket until we bind
   for(rp = res; rp != NULL; rp = rp->ai_next){
      sfd = socket(rp->ai_family, rp->ai_socktype, 0);
      if(sfd == -1) continue;
      if(bind(sfd, rp->ai_addr, rp->ai_addrlen) == 0) break;
      else close(sfd);
   }

   freeaddrinfo(res);

   if (rp == NULL){
      fprintf(stderr, "Could not bind to any socket\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   // Set the TCP socket to listen state
   if (listen(sfd, LISTEN_BACKLOG) == -1) handle_error("listen");

   for(;;){
      // Accept
      peer_addr_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_storage);
      cfd = accept(sfd, (struct sockaddr *) &peer_addr, &peer_addr_len);
      if (cfd == -1) handle_error("accept");

      // Fork
      pid_t pid = fork();

      if (pid == 0){
         //Child code
         char buf[BUF_SIZE];
         while(1){
             ssize_t nread = recv(cfd, buf, BUF_SIZE, 0);
             if (nread == 0) {
                 close(cfd);
                 exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
             } else {
                 ssize_t nsent = send(cfd, buf, nread, 0);
                 if (nsent != nread) fprintf(stderr, "Error sending response");
             }

         }
      } else {
         //Parent code

      }
   }
   close(sfd);
}
```

It compiles just fine, but when I try running it as `tcp_server 127.0.0.1 80` it gives me the error message `Could not bind to any socket`.

In my understanding, this should have bound the server to the IPv4 loopback address, port 80, and then I would have been able to interact with it using `netcat`.

What is going on?

Comment: Are you running your executable as root?

Comment: only root can bind ports under 1025 because they are reserved ports, so as already said, you must run your program as root or use a port > 1024

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Low-numbered ports are considered privileged by most operating systems. Try with a port like 8000 or 8080.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are passing port 80 via command line argument i.e. ARGV[2]. The Port No. 80 is the port number assigned to commonly used internet communication protocol, Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP).

You can use the port according to the below classification: 
 1. Ports 0–1023 – system or well-known ports
 2. Ports 1024–49151 – user or registered ports
 3. Ports >49151 – dynamic / private ports

So by this might, your problem will get solved.